# Modify router port-forwarding rules from Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, network, router

I'm trying to modify my router's NAT Table / Port-forwarding rules using the terminal on my Mac. My current setup looks something like this

```
Public  <->  Internet  <->  Modem + Router (1.1.1.1)  <->  Macbook (192.168.1.2)
```

There's a webserver / app running on port 7919 on my Macbook and I'd like to port-forward it so anyone can access it publicly from the internet. Specifically, I want `1.1.1.1:7919` to forward data to `192.168.1.2:7919`.

I know I can do this by going in to the Router settings web interface, or using other GUI apps such as [PortMap](http://codingmonkeys.de/portmap/), but I need to do this using the command line.

I've been searching for a solution for hours and still haven't been able to find a simple solution that does this for me. The closest I came was to [`natd`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/natd.8.html), but it has been deprecated in favor of [`pfctl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/pfctl.8.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/8/pfctl), and I can't make any sense of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for hours, I still wasn't able to find a built-in command-line utility that does what I'm asking for. But I did find something else that's pretty close. It's [**PortMapper**](https://github.com/kaklakariada/portmapper), a java applet that comes with a command-line interface to manage the port-mappings of your router (must be UPnP compatible).

Since my plan was to do everything from the terminal, I'll walk you through the steps:

```bsh
# Download the latest version
curl -fSL "https://sourceforge.net/projects/upnp-portmapper/files/latest/download" -o portmapper.jar

# See the basic help
java -jar portmapper.jar -h

# List all port-forwarding rules
java -jar portmapper.jar -list

# Create a new rule
java -jar portmapper.jar -add -externalPort 7919 -internalPort 7919 -ip 192.168.1.2 -protocol tcp

# Delete a rule
java -jar portmapper.jar -delete -externalPort 7919 -protocol tcp
```

---

*This assumes you have java installed and available in your shell*